# parenting object to an object deformed by armature

Tags: armature, parent

I have a cat figure rigged by an armature. Also, I have created some details as separate objects (teeth, eyes) primarily for texturing purposes. Is it possible to parent these details to the cat so that they move when I change the pose of the cat with the armature?

Many thanks

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

You can select the teeth, then the body, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join. But at this point, the teeth vertices won't be part of any vertex group, therefore no bone will be able to move them. So you also need to assign these vertices to the vertices group that they are supposed to be part of, i.e. the group that has the same name as the bone that controls it: Select the teeth vertices, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*, select the right group and press the *Assign* button.

You don't need to join the 2 objects if you don't want to, in that case parent the teeth to the armature *With Empty Group*, then in *Edi*t mode select the whole teeth mesh and assign it to the vertices group it is supposed to be part of.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is actually pretty helpful and probably solved a problem I would encounter somewhere down the road (I didn't know the joined object would not be a part of the vertex group). However, I was hoping this could be done without actually joining the two meshes together so that I am able to easily edit (and texture) the attached objects if I chose to. Do you think this is possible at all? I think I saw a video from Zacharias Reinhard a while ago, where he used some kind of a third object to manipulate the whole group of meshes (like a lattice), but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: You don't need to join the 2 objects if you don't want, in that case parent the teeth to the armature With Empty Group, then in Edit mode select the whole teeth mesh and assign it to the vertices group it is supposed to be part of. But you need to know that if you join you will still be able to easily change the material of the joined object.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you Ctrl+J to join with the teeth in the place you want them to be on the cat then it will be part of the main cat body. Then you should be done there. I'm pretty sure from experience this will help you :)